# how to call Android NDK function from Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, plugins, android-ndk

I have a library compiled with Android NDK.

In my .cpp file:

```
extern "C" {
    void helloFromNative() {
       // write something to a log, for example...
    }
}
```

From Unity, I try to call the native function directly, without having any Java wrapper, just like this tutorial: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html

```
[DllImport("mylib")]
private static extern void helloFromNative();
```

Well, nothing happens. Is there are anything else that needs to be done? Do I need a Java wrapper? or I can call Android native code directly from Unity?

Comment: What's the name of the ".so" file? How do you know it's not working? Try to make the function return an int and see what happens.

Comment: libmylib.so, i know it doesn't work because it doesn't write to the log as desired

Comment: I said return an int value instead of using log because you might have missed the log. Anyways, where did you put the plugin file in Unity?